# Map Fragment(Kotlin) onMapReady not working

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a map in a fragment and I am able to show the map but the `onMapReady` is not working as Its not adding the marker and not moving the camera. 
**Code**

MapFragment

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

   private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    companion object {
        var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment?=null
        val TAG: String = MapFragment::class.java.simpleName
        fun newInstance() = MapFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

            mapFragment = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.fallasMap) as SupportMapFragment?
            mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".fragments.MapFragment">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fallasMap"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The application never enter in the `onMapReady` I have added a breakpoint but never stop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your using the wrong fragment manager to access it. Since it's a fragment within a fragment, it's added to the `childFragmentManager`.

```
childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fallasMap) as SupportMapFragment
```

Also use the `as?` cast operator instead of casting to the optional type. Or even do a normal cast, since you need the fragment to be correct and `null` would be a bug.

Also don't store a static reference to the fragment if you don't clean it up properly.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud pass Value googleMap to mMap to InterAct with your markers

```
        override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap 
       // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in  
        Sydney"))
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
      }
```

Comment: I'm passing the value, but its not working. The application never enter in the `onMapReady` I have added a breakpoint but never stop. @ahmed-jamal

Comment: try to use childSupportFragment manager instead of fragmentManager

Comment: you are rigth, So I updated the code to ``mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fallasMap) as SupportMapFragment?`` and its working :). Just update your answer to accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Using `childFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager` is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to share these variables globale in your case, You should remove them from the `companion object` and create a new instance each time you open fragment.

When the `rootView != null` the `onMapReady` method won't called.

So I suggesting to remove them from `companion object` and put them in `onCreateView` without the condition `if (rootView == null)`(remove the condition).

Comment: The marker will be always the same, so I don't need to edit the map ones is created. But the main problem is the application never enter in the onMapReady and I don't know why.

Comment: @gon250 **I don't need to edit the map ones is created**, so you need to use another way, `saveInstance` for example, because the current way is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `supportFragmentManager` to find `SupportMapFragment`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
    mapFragment = supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.fallasMap) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

    return rootView
}
```

If you're not customizing you fragment then inside your XML file too

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/fallasMap"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: For some reason, this worked for me when childFragmentManager didn't. My code is almost exactly the same as OP's, except I'm using viewBindings. Curious why / what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
    val mapFragment = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
    

}
```

Comment: Please provide some detail for further information.